# Log the output as text file in SSIS Execute SQL Task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am in the process of creating SSIS package to call stored procedure in sql server database. I have four stored procedures. I have to call as a sequence like the below.

```
proc1
proc2
proc3
proc4
```

I want to log the output of results to a file. If the all the stored procedure are executed successfully then I need to write "Success" to the file. When the stored procedures return any error then I have to write the error to the file.

Kindly provide any suggestion to do this process efficiently.

I am new to SSIS.

I tried the following.
1. Created Execute SQL task.
2. Added Stored procedure calls with parameters.
3. Declared variables at SSIS package level.
4. I don't know how to write the status to file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [built in logging feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167456(v=sql.110).aspx) when designing the package.

More detailed documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140246(v=sql.110).aspx).